# Pass value of select_tag with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Example:

How can I ask the user for their `gender` with a `select_tag`, and then pass the value through a link?

**HTML.ERB**

```
<%= select_tag "gender", "<option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option>".html_safe %>

<%= link_to "Gender Evaluation", gender_eval_path(info: {gender: params[:gender]} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `on:change` event listener to your select tag, and in according function replace `href` attribute for your link.

example:

assume your select tag has class `gender-select` and link `submit-link`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gender-select').on('change', function(){
        $('.submit-link).attr('href', 'some_url/?gender'+ $('.gender-select').val();
    })
})
```

Replace `some_url` with real url

Comment: Could you give an example of what would be the correct answer?